# Computing Pointwise Limits

Tags: real-analysis

How would you find the pointwise limit of 
$$\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)}{n}$$
I'm confused on where to begin.

Answer (score 6):

If we're computing the pointwise limit, we would be evaluating
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{x/n}}{n}
$$
We could simply solve this as
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^{x/n}}{n} 
&= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{x/n}\right)\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&= (1)(0)\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

Thus, the pointwise limit of the function is zero.

We would then find that the series of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ given by $f_n(x)=\frac{e^{x/n}}{n}$ does **not** converge uniformly, since each $f_n$ is unbounded.

---

**Proof that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$:**

Take any $\epsilon>0$.  Choose $N\in\mathbb N$ so that $N>\dfrac{e}{\epsilon}$.  We note that for any $n>N$, for any $x\in[0,1]$
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f_n(x)-0\right|&=\left|f_n(x)\right|\\
&=\frac{e^{x/n}}{n}\\
&\leq \frac{e^{1/n}}{n}\\
&\leq \frac{e^1}{n}\\
&< \frac{e}{N}<\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
We conclude that $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But if the function continues to increase to infinity how is its limit 0?

Comment: The limit of this sequence of functions is zero in the following sense: at any point $x$, $f_n(x)$ can get as close to $0$ as you want it to be as long as you choose a big enough $n$.

Comment: then how would you show it does converge uniformly on [0,1]. I have gone through the proof by definition of uniform convergence and chose my N=N/(e^(1/N) but am not sure this is correct?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get that.  For a given choice of $\epsilon>0$, which $N$ do you take?

Comment: $\frac{N}{e^\frac{1}{N}}$? I'm pretty sure I missed some simplification and obtained an incorrect answer here but I am unsure what else to do

Comment: You can't define your choice of $N$ in terms of $N$, that's not how these proofs work.  I'll add to my answer.

Comment: would it be $1/2\epsilon$?

Comment: I wrote a working proof above.  Do you see what I did there and why I did it?

Comment: I overlooked the proof above (I ended up here by chance from clicking the wrong bookmark I had from several years ago), and I voted up on the above solution, accordingly; however, in the very last step in the case when considering all $x\in[0,1]$...I think you mean $\cdots<\dfrac{e}{N}<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{1}<\varepsilon$, as your initial choice of $N>0$ is $N>\dfrac{e}{\varepsilon}$ (i.e, it isn't $N=\dfrac{e}{\varepsilon}$).  I'm sorry to be a stickler on the solution as I took the $=$ sign as a simple typo, I figured, but the change yields a correct solution in its entirety.

Comment: @Procore thanks, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework question, I am not going to solve it. I will provide the intuition.

For pointwise convergence, you want to show that for any given $x$, the function converges to zero. In this sense, you fix $x$, and show that the sequence converges. This is what the others have done.

For uniform convergence, there has to be an $n$ such that all values of the function are sufficiently close to the pointwise limit of the function.

To prove that it does not converge pointwise you just have to show that for any given $n$, there is some $x$ for which the value is of $$f(x,n)-lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} > m$$ where $m$ is fixed at some value. In this case for a given $n$, you can find x such that

$$f(x,n)-0>1$$

For instance $n = 1$

\begin{align*}
(x,n) &= \frac{exp\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{n}\\
&= exp(x) \cdot exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \frac{1}{n}\\
&= e^x e^1
\end{align*}
so any $x>-1$ is sufficient.

Comment: How is $$e^{x/n}=e^xe^{1/n}\;\;??$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following theorem

> Let $\{a_n\} \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{ b_n \} \in \mathbb{N}$ be
>   convergent sequences with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \alpha$ and
>   $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \beta$ Then
>   $\{a_n b_n\}_n \in \mathbb{N}$ is convergent and
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_n b_n) = \alpha \beta$$

Taking $a_n = \exp(\frac{x}{n})$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Calculating the limit of each sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}b_{n} = 0$ then applying the previous theorem to $\{ a_n \}$ and $\{ b_n \}$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n b_n = (1)(0) = 0$$